# Issue with knockout mapping plugin

Tags: knockout.js, mapping

I'm trying to use the knockout mapping plugin, but it's not binding data to my UI. Following is my code:

```
var model;

$(document).ready(function () {
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: SERVER_PATH + '/jqueryservice/DataAccessService.asmx/GetData',
    async: false,
    data: "{ }",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (result, status) {
        model = ko.mapping.fromJS(result.d);
    },
    error: GetDataError

});

 });

 function GetDataError() {
     alert("System is not responding at the moment. Please try again.");
 }
```

Can anyone please let me know what am I doing wrong here? Following is the data that's returned from the server:

```
{"ID":903,"Name":"Camela Holding","Email":"Camelah@yahoo.com",
   "Vehicles":[{"ID":1,"Name":"Van"},
               {"ID":2,"Name":"Car"},
               {"ID":4,"Name":"Cadillac"},
               {"ID":5,"Name":"Train"},                         {"ID":3,"Name":"Jeep"}],
   "OwnerVehicle":0,"WeeklyData":null,"Week1":null}
```

Comment: try model = ko.mapping.fromJS(result);

Comment: Where do you call `ko.applyBindings(model);`?

Comment: What behaviour are you getting? An error alert or improper output? Your `result` does not have a `d`. Why is KO model bound to `result.d`?

Comment: Also, if you could illustrate the issue in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net), it would help us help you better.

Comment: @roman m: tried this still the same.

Comment: @nemesv - I had added ko.applyBindings(model) just below the mapping call, still the same. Also, I'm not seeing any errors on the page, just that it's not data-binding. Nothing on the UI.                        Also, what I have shown as the data retrieved from server is the result.d (got the result.d at run time)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make this fix work in a similar situation, but I do not know the exact reason why and how it's working.

I was trying to bind an observable with AJAX response which was an array, using the knockout mapping plugin.

This is what I was doing initially:

```
   self.DataRows = ko.observableArray();
   $.ajax({
                url: '/Home/GetStudentList1',
                cache: false,
                type: 'post',
                data: self.GridParams,
                success: function (data) {                        
                    self.DataRows(ko.mapping.fromJS(data));
                },
                error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    console.log("error :" + XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
                    alert('There was an error in performing this operation.');
                }
            });
```

The data was getting mapped in the observable but the UI was not updating then I tried this

```
   $.ajax({
                url: '/Home/GetStudentList1',
                cache: false,
                type: 'post',
                data: self.GridParams,
                success: function (data) {
                    var observableData = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
                    self.DataRows(observableData());
                },
                error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    console.log("error :" + XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
                    alert('There was an error in performing this operation.');
                }
            });
```

with the only difference that I took it in a variable before mapping it with my observable.
Similarly in your case I think you should try something like:

```
var self = this; //save reference to this as you will it in ajax success
self.model = ko.observable(); //create your observable
 $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: SERVER_PATH + '/jqueryservice/DataAccessService.asmx/GetData',
            async: false,
            data: "{ }",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
        success: function (result, status) {
                 var data = ko.mapping.fromJS(result.d);// don't have any idea what is making knockout happy doing it this way?
                 self.model(data());
    },
        error: GetDataError

    });
```

In both the cases when I was doing console.log(DataRows()) the structure of the observable was same.

Answer (score 0):

Well here is the answer to our question -

Try this

```
var model  = ko.observable();
$(document).ready(function () {
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: SERVER_PATH + '/jqueryservice/DataAccessService.asmx/GetData',
      async: false,
      data: "{ }",
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      dataType: "json",
success: function (result, status) {
    model(ko.mapping.fromJS(result.d)()); //mapped using braces ()
},
error: GetDataError

   });

 });
```

Notice the only difference here is that I made your model observable and instead of 
        model = ko.mapping.fromJS(result.d));
I used
       model(ko.mapping.fromJS(result.d)());

Instead of mapping my JSON objects into the array now I am mapping my observable.As you must be aware that all observable becomes function and their values are accessed using these braces"()" like functions.

Only because of this reason it was working when I took it into a separate variable and then accessed it using the braces.